# How Dynamic format string using keydown

Tags: c#

I want to change text as the user types values into a textbox.

This way:

```
1 = 1
12 = (12) 
123 = (12) 3
1234 = (12) 34
```

I made this code:

```
private void txtFoneres_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string p1 = e.KeyData.ToString();
    if (p1.StartsWith("D"))
    {
        p1 = p1.Replace("D", "");
    }
    if (p1.StartsWith("NumPad"))
    {
        p1 = p1.Replace("NumPad", "");
    }

    if (txtFoneres.TextLength == 1)
    {

        txtFoneres.Text = txtFoneres.Text + "(" + p1 + ")";
        txtFoneres.SelectionStart = 2;
        txtFoneres.SelectionLength = 2;
    }
}
```

Using my code, result was bellow:

```
"1" = "1 
"12" = "1(2" (this is the problem, it would have to start with "("
```

Does anyone know how to solve it and change 1(2 for (12)?

Comment: What are the exact rules you are seeking for your "()" insertion? If 2 or more number add () around the first two?

Comment: It's like you are trying to recreate a mask input? There are controls that could do that if you are using WinForms or WebForms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to use a [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
with a line of code like

```
private void maskedTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (maskedTextBox1.Text.Length == 1)
    {
        maskedTextBox1.Mask = "(00) 00";
        maskedTextBox1.SelectionStart = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: problem is that format isnt good, it show (  ) when nothing is typed on field, i really not understand this, i would like to make it appears after user start type

Comment: Leave the Mask property empty until after your user inputs the first digit.